# TensorFlow Root being imported and many methods not registering

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, tensorflow, visual-studio-2019

I've spent the last few hours trying to install TensorFlow (non-GPU) and it still not working. I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I have used an admin CMD to `pip install tensorflow`, and it was successful (or seems so). I can see in `%appdata%\..\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\` that the folders `tensorboard`, `tensorboard-2.0.1.dist-info`, `tensorflow`, `tensorflow_core`, `tensorflow_estimator`, `tensorflow_estimator-2.0.1.dist-info`, and `tensorflow-2.0.0.dist-info` all exist. I ran `pip` multiple times to make sure that everything for TensorFlow was installed and up-to-date. I also followed the instructions in the installation guide for TensorFlow to verify the installation with `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"`, which didn't give an error (also did not output anything, but I'm assuming it's not supposed to).

So I think my actual installation is fine, but perhaps this is a Visual Studio issue? Here's my Python code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(1, name="a")
b = tf.Variable(2, name="b")
f = a + b

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as s:
    init.run()
    print(f.eval())
```

As soon as I press "Start" to start the program, Visual Studio says "Exception Unhandled" and explains "module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'". The Python Console window then gives the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 39, in debug
    run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\[ME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\[ME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\[ME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\[ME]\Documents\Programming\Python\Tutorials\Simplest_Tensorflow_Application.py", line 8, in <module>
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'
```

When I hover my mouse over "`tensorflow`" in `import tensorflow as tf`, it VS says "TensorFlow root package". I'm not sure if that's what's supposed to be there or if the root package is something different.

If anyone has any suggestions on this, please let me know. I've tried for a while to get this to work and it's become rather frustrating. If anyone needs to know, I'm running a laptop with an SSD, 8GB DDR3 RAM, an Intel Core i7 3540M (Ivy Bridge) CPU, an integrated graphics card Intel HD Graphics 4000, and a dedicated graphics card NVIDIA NVS 5200M.

Even more information:
I had tried to install TensorFlow some time ago and had accidentally downloaded `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu`. I have manually uninstalled them both through Visual Studio (which seemed to have removed them from the actual Python directory, not just in a virtual environment) and reinstalled just `tensorflow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted and remade the VS solution. It seems Visual Studio was not updating its packages or something.